# Performance : Caml query taking long time to load or something else

Tags: 2010, document-library, caml-query, folder, spquery

I have a CAML query which provides a result, if a SPfolder exists or not.
When i do the item.Count it takes around 2sec for the line to execute . What is going wrong and taking long time to execute the query ?

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>" +         folderName + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";

//Retrieve the items based on Query                
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                                //if (!folderExists)
if (items.Count == 0)
{
//Operation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many fields are in here? Is it a standard document library, or did you add some extra metadata? Even if it is normal, do you *need* to pull all of the fields in question? Try modifying the ViewFields attribute of your query to return only the stuff that you need. Otherwise, you're traversing all of the folders (the "RecursiveAll" scope attribute); if you have a large library, particularly one with lots of levels, that may well take a while. If on the other hand you have a good idea of what folder the item might be in, you might consider cutting the search down to a single subfolder.

Comment: EDIT : 
PERFORMANCE NIGHTMARE CODE :
Never write the below code to check folder exists or not.                                 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Folders.Count; i++)
    {
    if (list.Folders[i].Folder.Name == folderName)
    {
       folderExists = true;
       folderItem = list.Folders[i];
       break;
     }

Comment: Yeah. At the very least, if you were going to do that, what you need to do is get a list of just the folder names and then iterate over *that*. If you have to do it more than once per call (for example, if you're checking to see if a library has been set up for business needs), convert the ListItemCollection you get back from your initial query into a collection of strings first.